# rabl how to get attribute from parent

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rabl

I have the following rabl code:

```
object @user

attributes :id, :email, :created_at, :last_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_ip, :authentication_token

child :info do
  attributes :first_name, :last_name
end

child :bundles do
  attributes :bundle_id_ecp
  child :products do
    attributes :product_id_ecp
  end
end

child :email_addresses do
  attributes :address
end

child :activities do
  attributes :data
end
```

User  has_many :activities and

:activities belongs to an activity_type model like so:

```
class ActivityType < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :activities

  attr_accessible :name
  validates_uniqueness_of :name

end
```

how do I access the :name attribute from activity_types in my :activities rabl?